# Why don't I have to set JAVA_HOME when installing Tomcat?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

Looks like I do not need to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable when installing Tomcat, anyone can confirm?

Comment: Maybe because it was already set before?

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal, then type:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

If java_home is set, you'll see a value. I have Tomcat running on my debian server, without java_home set. Why it works? I don't know for certain, but probably because of the use of standard directories for Java, so Tomcat knows where to look. If java is not there, it will complain during installation or during execution.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37822/how-do-i-install-apache-tomcat-7), it seem you are right. You need to setup a `$JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: Ah, I got it all wrong. He do needs to set up java_home, but it does not have any input for this when installing Tomcat...